# Python Error Number 22 for Certain Filenames (?)

Tags: python

So I am using a library called Newspaper3k (documentation - https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and have created the following glitchy program. It basically takes the newspaper articles and then proceeds to download and parse them (which takes place without error). In the next part of the program, it saves each article as a text file with a specific name. However, this program tends to "glitch" - while it will work for most articles, sometimes it will give me an "Error number 22".

```
>>> import newspaper
>>> bbc = newspaper.build('http://www.bbc.com/news')
>>> for x in bbc.articles:
      x.download()
      x.parse()
      content = x.text
      name = x.title
      authors = x.authors
      f = open ('%s,written by following: \n %s.txt' % (name,authors), 'w+')
      f.write(content)
      f.close()

   32
   142
   135
   146
   126
   138
   137
   175
   13
   164
   133
   177
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 7, in <module>
    f = open ('%s,written by following: \n %s.txt' % (name,authors), 'w+')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'BBC World News: 24 hour news TV 
channel,written by following: \n [].txt'
```

The output, although fine at first, ends up glitching. 
Could someone please help me? I'm an amateur. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error output? That error output should clear up whether the problem is downloading the data, parsing it, or writing it to a file.
Should your filename really contain a newline and a colon? This will not work on some operating systems (for instance, on Windows a colon has special meaning), and will be a pain to work with.

Comment: Can anyone at least tell me how to run the loop so it skips over a article which causes an error?

Comment: Please and Thank You.

Comment: On which operating system are you running this code? What is your Python version?
You can use a [try..catch statement](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to catch the error, but it would be much better to fix it.
Also note that **your current code contains a serious security vulnerability**: it allows anyone with control over the article name or author to write arbitrary files to your disk! You should really use sane file names, for instance a numeric ID or a hash of the URL.

Comment: Operating System - Windows 10

Comment: Python Version 3.6.4.

Comment: Thanks so much! Error Number 22 has never shown up again!

Comment: How did you do it? Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Are these comments supposed to go under my answer? If so, please comment there. And what precisely do you want to know what the code does? As I said in the answer, the trick is to simply delete all problematic characters.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the colon `:` has special meaning in paths, as do have other names that could occur in the articles, including `\`, `/` etc. .

If you must have the article name in the filename, only allow a list of well-known good characters:

```
import re
# ...
raw_name = '%s,written by following: \n %s.txt' % (name,authors)
safe_name = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_ .,]+', '', raw_name)
f = open(safe_name, 'w+')
```